# jQuery array of divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I make all the `div` elements in a container fade in one after each other without setting a delay for each `div` inside the container?

Here is my working jQuery code:

```
        $("#a").animate({opacity: '1'});
        $("#b").delay(100).animate({opacity: '1'});
        $("#c").delay(200).animate({opacity: '1'});
        $("#d").delay(300).animate({opacity: '1'});
        $("#e").delay(400).animate({opacity: '1'});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9poom60/2/

Now if I want to add one more `div`, I have to add it with a delay in my JavaScript and I have to add it in CSS. I'm pretty sure it can be done in a more simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container .some-div').each(function(i){
        $(this).delay(i*500).animate({opacity: 1},1000);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f9poom60/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop over that class, use index to set delay

```
$('.some-div').each(function (i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 100).animate({ opacity: '1'});
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f9poom60/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xudaR/54/)

One way you could do it would be to use an `each()` loop and fade them in:

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#word1, #word2, #word3, #word4, #word5').each(function(fadeInDiv){
     $(this).delay(fadeInDiv * 500).fadeIn(1000);
   });
});
```

Note I'm supplying a parameter, `fadeInDiv`, which will increment for each of the three elements `(returns 0, 1, 2)` and multiplying that by the delay, so you will get the delay incrementing accordingly `(0, 500, 1000)` etc.

Comment: This answer still requires editing the JavaScript (add the `div`'s ID) each time an HTML tag is added to `.container`.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be using jQuery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). This allows you to loop through any children of `.container`. Change `400*index` to speed up or slow the delay.

```
$(".container").children().each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400*index).animate({opacity:'1'},100);
});
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hdm3y042/)